# long file path is cluttering my mac terminal window when running python in vs code

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Im a newbie here. Whenever I run a python script in mac os terminal or in vs code, the generated output floods the terminal window, mostly with full paths of files etc see below:

*/Users/JohnSmith/opt/miniconda3/envs/py36env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py*

How can I adjust the level display, preferably toggling?

Im running zsh/oh-my-zsh where I display my current working directory but this does not extend to python running

thanks

Comment: Please add details - what script is it and what does the example output look like? Most probably it's the implementation of this particular script (maybe the logging configuration or similar).

Comment: Also, please add some screenshots and some info on where you are executing it, in vscode terminal or somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You most likely can't hide it. The Python extension for VS Code needs to use that path to execute your code so you can't hide it from a VS Code perspective. As for whether zsh would shrink the path post-execution, I would be a little surprised if it did as that's essentially mutating your history.